# Why is the SMS app crashing when sending SMSes to a three digits number?

Tags: sms, crashes

The SMS application crashes when I try to send an SMS to a three digits number. With other "regular" numbers, works just fine.
phone-HTC desire
Rom - AOKP Rom 4.2 JB
I tried to replace phone.apk,mms.apk, but that didn't work.

My logcat

```
V/SmsReceiverService( 7599): 
onStart: 
#1 mResultCode: 
-1 = Activity.RESULT_OK E/SmsUsageMonitor( 7089): 
Parsing pattern data found null E/SmsUsageMonitor( 7089): 
No patterns for "in": 
using generic short code rule D/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
Shutting down VM W/dalvikvm( 7089): 
threadid=1: 
thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41801930) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
java.lang.NullPointerException E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleConfirmShortCode(SMSDispatcher.java:1241) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.SMSDispatcher.handleMessage(SMSDispatcher.java:343) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmSMSDispatcher.handleMessage(GsmSMSDispatcher.java:116) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126) E/AndroidRuntime( 7089): 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) I/Process ( 7089): 
Sending signal. PID: 
7089 SIG: 
9 I/ServiceManager(  152): 
service 'iphonesubinfo' died I/ServiceManager(  152): 
service 'simphonebook' died I/ServiceManager( 152): 
service 'isms' died I/ServiceManager(  152): 
service 'phone' died I/ServiceManager(  152): 
service 'sip' died I/ActivityManager( 1137): 
Process com.android.phone (pid 7089) has died. W/ActivityManager( 1137): 
Scheduling restart of crashed service
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed information: Android Version, ROM type, Rom name, device name, etc.

Comment: 4.2.2 it is a custom aokp Rom.my device is HTC desire. Other custom roms working fine.May be a file is corrupted inside Rom.

Comment: @jerry: It's better to [edit] that information into your post. Comments are, by their nature, impermanent.

Answer (score 2):

Your SMS app is crashing because of an software bug, which is causing an uncaught `NullPointerException` resulting in a termination of the davlik VM and it's process.

Comment: any guesses to resolve this, I'm working on a custom Rom

Comment: Update the ROM to a newer version where the bug is (hopefully) fixed.

Comment: thanks for advice but I want to correct the error/software bug

Comment: You can't correct a software bug of the ROM without changing the ROM.

Comment: I probably can, I can decompile it, modify it. I just want to know which file causing that error so that I can replace with a good one .:)

Comment: It's usually easier to update the whole component instead of replacing only the faulty object code (although it certainly is possible).

Comment: ...not to mention, programming issues (including creating/modifying ROMs) are off-topic here.

Comment: @krampus where can I,I thought it was the right place.

Comment: @flow I admit it.I don't know the component causing the error either.
I tried to replace sms app(it probably contains SMSdispatcher.java file) but that didn't work.

Comment: Please see the [help/on-topic]. You might also look at [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371)